# Prevent camus from increasing the offset value

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-kafka, camus

Is there any way of preventing `camus` increase the offset value, and make it always read the previous value?

And also how to provide a custom name to the file that gets created instead of the general format i.e. `topic.leaderId.partitionId.partitioner.encodePartition(context, key)`?

Answer (score 1):

File names of mapper's output get generated in `generateFileName` method of `com.linkedin.camus.etl.Patitioner` class.

You can implement a custom Partitioner and provide a logic in as

`@Override
  public String generateFileName(JobContext context, String topic, String brokerId, int partitionId, int count,
      long offset, String encodedPartition) {
    return "MyCustomFileName-"+topic+partitionId;
  }`